# Puppeteer page.click doesn't work in headless mode

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

#### What's the problem

I try to click some element using Puppeteer, and I tried both `page.click` and `page.evaluate` on this task.

- If in `headless=false` mode, both approaches work well.
- If in `headless=true` mode, `page.evaluate` works, but `page.click` *hangs forever*.

What I did then, is `page.waitForSelector` explicitly for the element before `page.click`, see code below.

And looks like `waitForSelector` hangs forever too.

Could anyone help me to understand why it hangs in headless mode?

#### Env

```
chrome version is HeadlessChrome/80.0.3987.0
puppeteer version 2.1
macOS catalina 10.15.3
```

#### Code

```
const pptr = require('puppeteer');

console.log(pptr.version);

(async () => {
    var br = await pptr.launch({
        headless: true,
        defaultViewport: null,
        args: [
            '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36',
            '--user-data-dir=/tmp/user_data/',
        ],
    });
    var page = await br.newPage();
    var url = 'https://www.lookfantastic.com/brands/aesop/view-all.list';
    var css = 'div.responsiveProductListPage_topPagination button[aria-label="next page" i]:not([disabled])';

    const chrome_version = await page.browser().version();
    console.log(`chrome version is ${chrome_version}`);

    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitForSelector(css, { visible: true });  // when headless=true, hangs here.

    await Promise.all([
        page.click(css),
        //page.evaluate((css) => { document.querySelector(css).click(); }, css),
        page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0'}),
    ]);
    console.log('success');
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    await br.close();
})();
```

Comment: Have you tried taking a screenshot in headless mode?

Comment: @Capripot, great advice, let me try now, will be back in a minute.

Comment: @Capripot, I tried setting a large viewport size, and now `page.click` worked, thanks so much man :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on your comment, the screen in headless might not be of the right size for the element you are testing. Does this element is supposed to be shown on laptop sized screen (width > 1200px in your case)?

You can set the window size of Puppeteer with the option `--window-size=width,height`, for instance:

```
args: [
            '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36',
            '--user-data-dir=/tmp/user_data/',
            '--window-size=1200,800',
        ],
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, and could you explain why `page.evaluate` worked before setting the window size?

Comment: I mean, `page.evaluate` might not click on the right thing, but it didn't hang.

Comment: It might be that `querySelector` doesn't take the element's visibility in account, only locate the element, and click the supposed location.

Comment: '--start-maximized' may be of help as well .

Comment: @AlferdNobel `--start-maximized` might not work properly in headless mode

Answer (score 2):

I found that a more proper way of preventing this issue would be calling hover before click, like this:

```
await page.hover(selector)
await page.click(selector)
```

This way, the browser will scroll to the selector, ensuring it is visible and can be clicked, regardless of window size.